# Variable is not getting updated in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, urlsession

My SwiftUI app has a class which parses JSON Data.
As you can see from the comments near the `print`, I do not understand while the line `print("return: " + self.productName)` print the variable still empty (basically the initialized one).
Why is the variable updated inside the if block, but not outside?

Any idea?
Thanks.

---

```
class ProductDecoer: ObservableObject {

  @Published var productName: String = ""

  func checkBarCode(barcode: String) -> String {

    let api = <url>
    let barcode = barcode
    let format = ".json"
    let url = URL(string: api + barcode + format)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { [self] data, response, error in
      if let data = data {
        if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
          productName = self.getProductInfo(json: jsonString)
          print("checkBarCode: " + self.productName) // --> print correctly
        }
      }
    }.resume()

    self.productName = productName
    print("return: " + self.productName) // --> is empty
    return self.productName
  }

  func getProductInfo(json: String) -> String {
    let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)!
    let productInfo: ProductInfo = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ProductInfo.self, from: jsonData)
    self.productName = productInfo.product_name
    print("AAA: " + self.productName)
    print("Prodotto: " + productInfo.product_name)

    productName = productInfo.product_name
    print("CC: " + productName)

    return productName
  }

  struct ProductInfo: Codable {

    var code: String
    var product_name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case code
      case product

      enum ProductCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case product_name
      }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let rootContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      let productContainer = try rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.ProductCodingKeys.self, forKey: .product)

      code = try rootContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .code)
      product_name = try productContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .product_name)

      print("BB: " + product_name)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var rootContainer = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      var productContainer = rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.ProductCodingKeys.self, forKey: .product)

      try rootContainer.encode(code, forKey: .code)
      try productContainer.encode(product_name, forKey: .product_name)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`URLSession.shared.dataTask` is an *asynchronous* function. That means that it executes independently and finishes an an indeterminate time in the future.

What you provide to it inside the `{ }` that follows it is called a completion handler or callback function -- this is the code that `dataTask` *will* call after its execution finishes, so anything that depends on the returned value needs to happen inside that closure.

Unfortunately, that means you won't be able to return `String` directly from your `checkBarCode` function. But, you can create a callback function for it as well:

```
func checkBarCode(barcode: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        
        let api = "URL"
        let barcode = barcode
        let format = ".json"
        let url = URL(string: api + barcode + format)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { [self] data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    self.productName = self.getProductInfo(json: jsonString)
                    print("checkBarCode: " + self.productName)
                    completion(self.productName)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Which can be called like this:

```
checkBarCode(barcode: "") { productName in 
  //do something that depends on the value
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot; I am calling this function from another class, that means I have to do something like this: var productDecoder = ProductDecoder() productDecoder.checkBarCode("xyz") { productName in } ?

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `productDecoder` in there... But, with an asynchronous function, you usually want to hold a reference to the object doing the calling. So, store a `ProductionDecoder()` instance somewhere and then call `productDecoder.checkBarCode...` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) ...` is an asynchronous task. This means that the closure which you pass in `[self] data, response, error` will be called *after* the URL request has been made. The `print` statement below will therefore be run before the URL request has been completed which is why it is empty.

The `print` inside the closure has the correct value because it has been fetched by that time.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `ProductDecoer` class conforms to `ObservableObject` and the property `productName` is published using @Publisher you don't need to return anything from the function `checkBarCode`so change the signature of the function to

```
func checkBarCode(barcode: String) { ... }
```

and remove everything after `.resume()` in it.

Then in your SwiftUI view you create a property for the class and use the @ObservedObject property

```
@ObservedObject var decoder = ProductDecoer()
```

Below is a complete but simple example of a view that will request the product name for the bar code given in a text field when a button is pressed. Once the information has been downloaded the published property `productName` will be set and the view will display it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var decoder = ProductDecoer()
    @State private var barCode: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField("Bar code", text: $barCode)
            Text(decoder.productName)

            Button {
                decoder.checkBarCode(barcode: barCode)
            }
            label: {
                Text("Load")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```